# quickfixj Market Data can't get group field

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

"8=FIX.4.29=11435=W49=TEST56=MYTEST234=552=20180614-21:36:4955=HKGUSD268=2269=0270=1.0271=20269=1270=0.0271=0262=010=179"
My scala processes this with "58=Conditionally Required Field Missing372=X"

Here is the code snapit:

```
msg: MarketDataIncrementalRefresh
val group = new MarketDataIncrementalRefresh.NoMDEntries()
msg.getGroup(1, group) // this is already throwing out that error
```

I pasted the fix message to the online parser and seems ok to get all the field back.
My cfg file has UseDataDictionary=N would this matter?

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed by adding the data dictionary and xml files to the configuration. And it seems that this is only required when parsing repeating groups.

Comment: Indeed, when a message has repeating groups in it, you need a data dictionary.

Comment: Yes, but it took me around 3 hours to get to that. quickfixj should have this in the documentation

Comment: It's a bit buried, but here: [Configuring QuickFIX/J](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.1/usage/configuration.html) - UseDataDictionary: `Tell session whether or not to expect a data dictionary. You should always use a DataDictionary if you are using repeating groups.`